# JavaScript: Re-organize canvas rendering in a functional manner

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, coding-style

Is there a better or more "functional" way to organize this code?

```
let activeCanvas = null;

export function createLayer() {
    if (activeCanvas)
        activeCanvas.disableInteraction();

    let newCanvas = createCanvas({ transparent: !!activeCanvas});

    let parentCanvas = activeCanvas;
    activeCanvas = newCanvas;

    return {
        stage: newCanvas.stage,
        destroy() {
            newCanvas.destroy();
            parentCanvas.enableInteraction();
            activeCanvas = parentCanvas;
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a new layer and returns the stage to the caller as well as the ability to destroy the layer again and then make the parent layer the active one.

Layers can stack above each other.

... what about this one "activeCanvas" variable which is module scoped? Is there a way to achieve this logic more "functional"-ly and winding it up on the call stack somewhere?

### Update

The code works fine as it is - this is just a question about style, elegance and how to program properly in a functional way.

I am happy with the code - I just feel like there is a more "enlightened" way to do it but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you supposed to update both the parent layer and active layer each time destroy is called or only the active layer and keep the same parent layer?

Comment: How are you using `createLayer`? Because right now you have state, i.e. `activeLayer` that is shared across all calls to `createLayer` and the `destroy` method, meaning all apis created by invoking `createLayer` share that state. It's effectively a singleton. In other words, any layer can change the `activeLayer` variable by calling its `destroy` method. Is this intended? Should `activeLayer` be a state per each layer created or for all layers?

Comment: It is supposed to be a "singleton" - it tracks the currently active layer so it can be destroyed again. On creation the currently active layer becomes the parent. On destruction the former parent becomes the active. This way I can nicely stack layers on top of each other and "undwind" again once they get destroyed. I am really only wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this via the call stack itself

Comment: Shouldn't you also update `parentCanvas`, each time you destroy? Otherwise, after the first call to `destroy`, this would be `true`: `parentCanvas === activeCanvas` and the next time around you'd be acting on the came canvas for both the parent and the active one

Comment: that is the intention: if the active layer gets destroyed, the parent becomes the new active

Comment: And how are you creating the layers, is there an event from the user like a click, a timer, or some programmatic condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: In my examples bellow, "transparent" canvas is blue and regular canvas is green. Disabled-interaction canvas has lower opacity than the enabled one.*

---

What you essentially have here is a form of a stack with some state encapsulation.

What you care about is:

1. Pushing an item to the top (adding a new layer)
2. Popping an item from the top (destroying a layer)
3. Keeping track of the current stage

```js
function createLayers(canvases = []) {
  function top() {
    return canvases[canvases.length - 1];
  }

  function disableTop() {
    const last = top();
    if (last) last.disableInteraction();
  }

  function enableTop() {
    const last = top();
    if (last) last.enableInteraction();
  }

  function destroyTop() {
    const last = top();
    if (last) last.destroy();
  }

  function push() {
    disableTop();
    canvases.push(createCanvas({ transparent: !!top() }));
    enableTop();
  }

  function pop() {
    destroyTop();
    canvases.pop();
    enableTop();
  }

  return {
    push,
    pop,
    stage: () => top().stage
  };
}

const layers = createLayers();

document.querySelector("#push").addEventListener("click", layers.push);

document.querySelector("#pop").addEventListener("click", layers.pop);

var createCanvas=function(e=0){return function(a={}){const t=e;e+=1;const n=document.createElement("div");return n.className=`fake-canvas ${a.transparent?"transparent":""}`,document.body.appendChild(n),n.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t)),{__elem:n,enableInteraction(){n.classList.remove("disabled")},disableInteraction(){n.classList.add("disabled")},destroy(){n.remove()}}}}();
```

```css
.fake-canvas{border:3px solid #018bbc;width:75px;height:50px;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;margin-left:10px;position:relative;}.fake-canvas.disabled{opacity:.5;pointer-events:none}body{height:100vh;display:flex;align-items:center}.fake-canvas.transparent{border-color:#2ecc71;}button{margin:5px;padding:10px;appearance:none;background-color:#018bbc;border:0;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase}#buttons{display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
```

```html
<div id="buttons"><button id="push">push</button><button id="pop">pop</button></div>
```

Another way to think of this is as a linked list.

To make things more functional, you want to introduce pureness and immutability into the list construction and modification.

A list is never mutated but instead, any modification creates a new list.

To handle canvas operations, we can introduce a side-effect function. To make things fully functional we'd actually want to create a new layer with a new canvas on each operation but that might be expensive so my example operates on the existing canvas.

```js
var createCanvas=function(e=0){return function(t){const a=e;e+=1;const n=document.createElement("div");return n.className=`fake-canvas ${t.transparent?"transparent":""}`,document.body.appendChild(n),n.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a)),{__elem:n,enableInteraction(){n.classList.remove("disabled")},disableInteraction(){n.classList.add("disabled")},destroy(){n.remove()}}}}();

// function to create a layer
function layer(prev) {
  return {
    canvas: createCanvas({ transparent: !!prev }),
    prev: typeof prev === 'function' ? prev : () => prev,
  };
}

// function to compose an array of functions
function compose(...fns) {
  return function composition(arg) {
    return fns.reduceRight((prevResult, fn) => fn(prevResult), arg);
  }
}

// generic canvas-side-effect-enducing function
function canvasSideEffect(name) {
  return function sideEffect(l) {
    if (l && l.canvas) {
      l.canvas[name]();
    }
    return l;
  }
}

// create functions to perform canvas side-effect operations
const enable = canvasSideEffect("enableInteraction");
const disable = canvasSideEffect("disableInteraction");
const destroy = canvasSideEffect("destroy");

const push = compose(
  enable, // then we enable the new layer's canvas
  layer,  // then we create a new layer
  disable // first we disable the top layer's canvas
)

const pop = compose(
  enable,                // then we enable the new top layer's canvas
  l => l ? l.prev() : l, // then we remove the layer
  destroy                // first we destroy the previous layer's canvas
)

let l;

document.querySelector("#push").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // each layer creation creates a new list
  l = push(l)
});

document.querySelector("#pop").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // each layer removal creates a new list
  l = pop(l);
});
```

```css
.fake-canvas{border:3px solid #018bbc;width:75px;height:50px;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;margin-left:10px;position:relative;}.fake-canvas.disabled{opacity:.5;pointer-events:none}body{height:100vh;display:flex;align-items:center}.fake-canvas.transparent{border-color:#2ecc71;}button{margin:5px;padding:10px;appearance:none;background-color:#018bbc;border:0;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase}#buttons{display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
```

```html
<div id="buttons"><button id="push">push</button><button id="pop">pop</button></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that module-scoped mutable variable is a definite code smell. Some OOP could fix that already, but let's make it functional. A stack structure is easily made immutable:

```
export function createLayer(parent) {
    if (parent)
        parent._canvas.disableInteraction();
    const canvas = createCanvas({ transparent: !!parent });
    return {
        _canvas: canvas,
        stage: canvas.stage,
        destroy() {
            canvas.destroy();
            if (parent) // I think you missed this
                parent._canvas.enableInteraction();
            return parent;
        },
        create() {
            return createLayer(this);
        }
    };
}
```

It's still a bit weird though because your *first* layer is special by being transparent. Also there is no data structure that represents the empty stack. To fix these issues, we can use

```
function createLayer(parent, parentCanvas, transparent) {
    parentCanvas.disableInteraction();
    const canvas = createCanvas({ transparent });
    return {
        stage: canvas.stage,
        destroy() {
            canvas.destroy();
            parentCanvas.enableInteraction();
            return parent;
        },
        create() {
            return createLayer(this, canvas, false)
        }
    };
}
export const noLayer = {
    canvas: null,
    destroy() {
        throw new Error("cannot pop the bottom of the layer stack");
    },
    create() {
        return createLayer(this, {
            disableInteraction() {},
            enableInteraction() {}
        }, true);
    }
};
```

The functionally-minded user of your library would then write something like

```
import { noLayer } from '…';

const a = noLayer.create();
const b = a.create();
const c = b.destroy(); // == a
const d = c.create();
const e = d.create();
const f = e.destroy(); // == d
const g = f.destroy(); // == c == a
const h = g.create();
const i = h.destroy(); // == g == c == a
const j = i.destroy(); // == noLayer
```